# How to wait for completion of all boost:asio's stackful coroutines?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

I'm starting a number of coroutines with asio::spawn, and I want to wait until all of then are finished and do some other work then. How it can be done?

The control flow is following:

```
asio::spawn (io, [] (asio::yield_context yield) {
  ...
  // starting few coroutines
  asio::spawn (yield, [] (asio::yield_context yield2) { ... });
  asio::spawn (yield, [] (asio::yield_context yield2) { ... });
  asio::spawn (yield, [] (asio::yield_context yield2) { ... });
  asio::spawn (yield, [] (asio::yield_context yield2) { ... });

  // now I want to wait for all of them to finish before I do 
  // some other work?
  ...
});

io.run ();
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the sample code

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <chrono>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  using namespace boost::asio;

  io_service io;

  spawn (io, [&] (yield_context yield) {
    cout << "main coro starts\n";

    auto lambda = [&] (yield_context yield)
      {
        cout << "in lambda inside subcoroutine - starts\n";
        steady_timer t (io, std::chrono::seconds (1));
        t.async_wait (yield);
        cout << "in lambda inside subcoroutine - finishes\n";
      };

    // starting few coroutines
    spawn (yield, lambda);
    spawn (yield, lambda);

    // now I want to wait for all of them to finish before I do
    // some other work?
    // ???

    cout << "main coro finishes\n";
  });

  io.run ();
}
```

And the output is:

```
// main coro starts
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - starts
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - starts
// main coro finishes <----
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - finishes
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - finishes
```

While I'm expecting:

```
// main coro starts
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - starts
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - starts
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - finishes
// in lambda inside subcoroutine - finishes
// main coro finishes
```

(see the place of "main coro finishes" line)

Comment: IIRC `io.run ();` just does what you want...

Comment: @vines - no, it is not. [Coliru Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e67cceb688156974)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a ... sort of workaround.

I can use a timer with infinite duration, and cancel it from last sub-coroutine. This will wake up the main coroutine.

[Coliru Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3d37953acc2e5cd)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  using namespace boost::asio;

  io_service io;

  spawn (io, [&] (yield_context yield) {
    cout << "main coro starts\n";


    steady_timer rendez_vous (io, steady_timer::clock_type::duration::max ());
    /* volatile */ int counter = 2;


    auto lambda = [&] (yield_context yield)
      {
        cout << "in lambda inside subcoroutine - starts\n";
        steady_timer t (io, boost::chrono::seconds (1));
        t.async_wait (yield);
        cout << "in lambda inside subcoroutine - finishes\n";

        if (--counter == 0)
            rendez_vous.cancel ();
      };

    // starting few coroutines
    spawn (yield, lambda);
    spawn (yield, lambda);

    // now I want to wait for all of them to finish before I do
    // some other work?
    // ???
    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
    rendez_vous.async_wait (yield [ignored_ec]);
    // ignore errors here by reason.

    cout << "main coro finishes\n";
  });

  io.run ();
}
```

Frankly I don't like this solution, because it abuses "timer" concept and object and it is a possible waste of system resources.

Comment: I like it anyways. Except for the abuse of `volatile`. If you want it thread-safe, use `atomic_int`. Otherwise, just leave it `int`

Comment: For what it is worth, I have used a timer as well when I had a similar need.  It provides a fairly portable solution, and with a few higher-level classes that abstract the implementation, it provides a fairly clean solution.  I believe `counter` can be a normal `int`, as all of those coroutines will run within the same `strand` with the appropriate memory barriers.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be using fibers (boost.fiber integrates into boost.asio).
a boost::fiber is a coroutine + scheduler + synchronization classes (API like std::thread) and can be used in the boost.asio context like coroutines.

Comment: I'm aware about boost.fiber and it is very interesting. But is it ready to try for production tasks? What do you personally think about it?